# Отображение встроеной памяти

Tags: android, kotlin, память

Не могу вывести количество встроеной памяти. Использую такой код:

```
    const val MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L
    ...
    fun getTotalInternalMemorySize() : String{
        val file : File = Environment.getRootDirectory()
        val statFs : StatFs = StatFs(file.path)

        return (statFs.blockSizeLong * statFs.blockCountLong).div(MEGABYTE).toString()
    }
```

Функция возвращает ~2000МБ но реальная память устройства 8Гб.

Answer (score 1):

> getRootDirectory()
>   Return root of the "system" partition holding the core Android OS.

Вы же смотрите размер только системного раздела.

Вот так для API9+ должно работать.

```
long freeBytesInternal = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getTotalSpace();
long freeBytesExternal = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()).getTotalSpace();
```

Comment: C internal storage все верно. Но external совсем не то. Погрешность в 1ГБ.